# Coordinate transformations and projection issues

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, projection, qglwidget

I've been trying for a while to get my mouse coordinates converted into 3D space coordinates in an OpenGL scene.

Currently, my projections are a little bit of a mess (I think), and it doesn't seem to fully take my "camera" into account when I move around a scene. To check this, I draw a line.

My resize function:

```
    void oglWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
    {
        if (height == 0) {
            height = 1;
        }
        pMatrix.setToIdentity();
        pMatrix.perspective(fov, (float) width / (float) height, -1, 1);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

My rendering function (paintGl()) goes as follows:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;

QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;
cameraTransformation.rotate(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
cameraTransformation.rotate(beta, 1, 0, 0);

QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(camX, camY, distance);
QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);
vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, QVector3D(camX, camY, 0), cameraUpDirection);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();    
gluLookAt(cameraPosition.x(), cameraPosition.y(), cameraPosition.z(), camX, camY, 0, cameraUpDirection.x(), cameraUpDirection.y(), cameraUpDirection.z());

shaderProgram.bind();
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("texture", 0);


for (int x = 0; x < tileCount; x++)
{
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", tiles[x]->vertices.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tiles[x]->image.width(), tiles[x]->image.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tiles[x]->image.bits());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tiles[x]->vertices.size());
}
shaderProgram.release();
```

And to create my Ray:

```
GLdouble modelViewMatrix[16];
GLdouble projectionMatrix[16];
GLint viewport[4];
GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMatrix);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionMatrix);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

winX = (float)x;
winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)y;
glReadPixels( winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );

GLdouble nearPlaneLocation[3];
gluUnProject(winX, winY, 0, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix,
             viewport, &nearPlaneLocation[0], &nearPlaneLocation[1],
        &nearPlaneLocation[2]);

GLdouble farPlaneLocation[3];
gluUnProject(winX, winY, 1, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix,
             viewport, &farPlaneLocation[0], &farPlaneLocation[1],
        &farPlaneLocation[2]);

 QVector3D nearP = QVector3D(nearPlaneLocation[0], nearPlaneLocation[1],
            nearPlaneLocation[2]);
 QVector3D farP = QVector3D(farPlaneLocation[0], farPlaneLocation[1],
            farPlaneLocation[2]);
```

I feel like I'm using conflicting systems or something.

Should I be using different variables to manage my camera? I see talk of projection view, model view, etc, but I don't see how I would use that and also use the shader program. I'm still novice when it comes to OpenGL.

**So to clarify:** I'm attempting to convert my mouse coordinates into 3D space coordinates. So far, it appears to semi-work, it just doesn't take into account camera rotation. I confirmed that my problem has to do with either the ray creation, or with the unprojection of coordinates, not with my actual ray picking logic.

Comment: Just so you know, in window-space the near plane is **0.0** and the far plane is **1.0**. You are using the wrong coordinates for `z`. Truthfully it probably won't matter unless you have a point that lies exactly on the near clipping plane.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to change that back. I've been frantically changing values trying to fix the problem before submitting it, I'll change that back.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's correct to simply negate the window system mouse coordinates. You want to change the origin from the top to the bottom, so it's usually something like `maxY - Y`.

Comment: I don't understand. In a 3d Cartesian system, the positive y axis is upwards, but in window systems it's downwards. Why wouldn't I flip it? At any rate, changing that value still doesn't remedy anything. Is it normal for unprojected coordinates to be that small? Is the scale of the opengl coordinate system smaller than the data passed to it? I mean, I don't scale my objects or anything.

Comment: You wouldn't flip it because for example, if you have a window with height 300, the **-300** in window-space you get by negating the input coordinates (**300**) is very different from **0** _(MaxY - InputY)_. The negated position refers to a position that is not even part of your viewport. Maybe it would help if you understood that it's not just the Y-axis direction that is different? The origin is also different. **0** is the top of the window in mouse coordinates, and **0** is the bottom in window-space.

Comment: Have you looked at some of the values (e.g. the matrices and viewport) in a debugger? Do they look reasonable?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I'm not sure how they should normally look, but for both the model and projection matrices, the spots at 0, 5, 10, and 15 are equal to 1, the rest are 0. The viewport matrix is just 0,0,1920,1080. Do these look right?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I found out that if I try to draw a point at the location of my ray **after** my shaderProgram is released at the end of my paintGL call, then the point is drawn at the right location on the screen, however it only draws on the viewport, not in 3D space, meaning it never changes as the camera rotates. Second, if I i call glFrustum() and then draw the point as above, it will work in 3D space, but it's position is on a totally different scale!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I think I had a series of problems.

1. I should have used -1 for my near plane, not 0
2. I had differing data types for my matrices (QT ones specifically,), making me unable to directly plug them into the unproject function.

I solved these by doing the following:

1. I installed the [GLM library](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/index.html) to normalize my data types
2. I performed the matrix calculations myself

- So I pulled the matrices into my ray creation function, then multiplied the inverse view matrix by the inverse model matrix, then by the inverse projection matrix.
- This value would then be multiplied in 2 different vectors of the screen coordinate (which had to be in NDC space). One with a z of -1, the other of +1 corresponding to the near and far planes of window space. Lastly, those vectors also had to have a "w" value of 1, so that the resulting calculation of matrix * vector could be divided by the last spot of itself.

I had a series of questions opened here because my initial problem of ray picking lead to revealing a whole series of errors in my code.
If anyone has come across the problem posted here, it may be worth checking out my other questions that I opened, as all of my problems all stem from projection issues:

- [In here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374185/ray-creation-for-raypicking-not-fully-working/), I learned that I actually need some form of calculations in order for ray creation.
- [In here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464025/unprojected-mouse-coordinates-are-between-0-1), I learned that unProject wasn't working because I was trying to pull the model and view matrices using OpenGL functions, but I never actually set them in the first place, because I built the matrices by hand. I solved that problem in 2 fold: I did the math manually, and I made all the matrices of the same data type (they were mixed data types earlier, leading to issues as well).
- [And lastly, in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518139/3d-scene-transformations-not-quite-working), I learned that my order of operations was slightly off (need to multiply matrices by a vector,  not the reverse), that my near plane needs to be -1, not 0, and that the last value of the vector which would be multiplied with the matrices (value "w") needed to be 1.

Since my problem extended over quite a great length of time, and took up several questions, I owe credit to a few individuals who helped me along the way:

- [srobins of facepunch](http://facepunch.com/member.php?u=674814), in [this thread](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1450824)
- [derhass from here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass), [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518139/3d-scene-transformations-not-quite-working), and this [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70929/discussion-between-yattabyte-and-derhass)

Answer (score 2):

It very much looks like you're being tripped up by mixing different feature groups/levels. You have some aspects of using the fixed function matrix stack. For example, in your drawing function:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();    
gluLookAt(cameraPosition.x(), cameraPosition.y(), cameraPosition.z(), camX, camY, 0, cameraUpDirection.x(), cameraUpDirection.y(), cameraUpDirection.z());
```

Or in your un-projection function:

```
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMatrix);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionMatrix);
```

But in other places, you're building your own matrices, and passing them into the shader as uniforms:

```
vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, QVector3D(camX, camY, 0), cameraUpDirection);
...
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);
```

These are two different ways of implementing the same functionality. But you can't just freely mix and match pieces of them. If you want to keep things clean and predictable, you should choose one, and stick with it. Since the first one is legacy functionality that is deprecated, I suggest you stick with building your own matrices, and using uniforms defined in your shader code.

As an example to illustrate why your current mix of features is a recipe for disappointment: You're getting the current projection matrix from the fixed function matrix stack with `glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ...)`. But at least in the code shown here, you're never specifying a projection matrix using the matrix stack. So this is just going to give you the identity matrix. As far as OpenGL is concerned, the `pMatrix` matrix you pass as a uniform to your shader program is completely unrelated.

Rewriting your whole code would be a little much for this answer, so here are just pointers for the critical parts:

- Get rid of all calls that refer to the matrix stack. This includes calls like `glMatrixMode()`, `glLoadIdentity()`, `gluLookAt()`, and the `glGetDoublev()` calls to get the current matrices.
- Use shaders for all your rendering (if you aren't already), and define all matrices you need as uniforms in your GLSL code.
- Calculate and manage matrices yourself, either using your own code, or one of the widely used matrix/vector libraries.
- Pass those matrices as uniforms to the shader.

Now, for the un-projection, it looks like you already have your model, view, and projection matrices (`pMatrix`, `vMatrix`, `mMatrix`). So there is no need for any `glGet*()` calls to retrieve them from OpenGL. Multiply `vMatrix` with `mMatrix` to get the `modelViewMatrix`, and use `pMatrix` directly as the projection matrix you pass to `gluUnProject()`.

Strictly speaking, I would also consider GLU deprecated. But if you're comfortable still using `gluUnProject()`, that might be easiest for now. Otherwise, commonly used matrix libraries are likely to have an implementation of it. Or if you're not afraid to get your hands dirty, it shouldn't be hard to implement if you look up some specs/documentation that explain the underlying calculations.